# Get file listing from directory to show in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, file, jcombobox, jtextarea

I have a simple GUI with few `JTextArea` components where user puts profile info.

After clicking "save" button all the info is converted into `String` array and saved as .txt using `File`.
You can create multiple profiles.

Inside `profilename.txt`:

```
profilename;name;lastname;age;address;...
```

**I want all the saved profiles to show up in a `JComboBox` so the user can select his profile and edit his inputs.**

So lets say I have a folder with profiles:

```
profileTest.txt  
profileMain.txt  
profileBruh.txt
```

How do I get these files to show up in a combo box?

Answer (score 1):

Read the `File` API.

You can use the `list()` or `list(FilenameFilter)` method to get a list of the files found in the directory.

Or as Andrew has suggested in the comment use the `listFile()` or `listFile(FilenameFilter)` method to store the actual File object in the combo box instead of just the String name of the File.

Then you iterate through the Array and use the `JComboBox.addItem(…)` method to add each filename to the combo box.

Comment: *"..add each filename to the combo box."* When I have a `File`, I prefer to add *that* to a `JComboBox` (`JList`, `JTable` ..) then use an appropriate renderer for the visual effect that is most pleasing (sometimes adding the file's icon, but there is little point when all the files are of the same file type). But apart from that caveat, yes, this.